# VBA Subscript out of range error trying to open file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a file and then find the last row, everything works up until this line:

> Set SourceSheet = crWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash Request Form")

It gives me an error of Subscript out of Range and I can't figure out why ...

```
 Dim filter As String
 Dim caption As String
 Dim crFilename As String
 Dim crWorkbook As Workbook
 Dim crMasterWorkbook As Workbook

 ' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
 Set crMasterWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 .AllowMultiSelect = False
 .InitialFileName = "*Cash Report*.xlsx"
 .Show
 crFilename = .SelectedItems(1)

 End With

 ' get the cash request workbook
 'caption = "Please Select an input file "
 'crFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

 Set crWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(crFilename, UpdateLinks = False)

 ' copy data from source to target workbook
 Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
 Set targetSheet = crMasterWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Cash Request Log")
 Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
 Set SourceSheet = crWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash Request Form")

 'Define last row
 target_lastrow = targetSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Your workbook (`crWorkbook`) has no sheet `"Cash Request Form"` - maybe a simple typo? Check especially the spaces.

Comment: If it doesn't look like a typo, look for a space before or after `"Cash Request Form"`